# Tag H1 is not working properly when dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.html = [{
    "name": "teste",
    "data": [{
        "tag": {
            "name": "h1",
            "text": "Titulo 1",
            "colValue": "col-xs-12"
        }
    }, {
        "tag": {
            "name": "text",
            "colValue": "col-xs-4"
        }
    }, {
        "tag": {
            "name": "h1",
            "text": "Titulo 2",
            "colValue": "col-xs-12"
        }
    }, {
        "tag": {
            "name": "text",
            "colValue": "col-xs-4"
        }
    }, {
        "tag": {
            "name": "text",
            "colValue": "col-xs-8"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "name": "teste",
    "data": [{
        "tag": {
            "name": "h1",
            "text": "Titulo 3",
            "colValue": ""
        }
    }, {
        "tag": {
            "name": "text",
            "colValue": "col-xs-4"
        }
    }]
}];
```

I having some issues creating a dynamically form using `javascript` (angular) and `bootstrap`. The idea is to create dynamically the html tags.

My issue:  `h1` is not rendering properly when `h1` > 1, it's not jumping to next line.

**First take a look here:**  http://jsfiddle.net/92z54z04/951/

**It needs to be like this way:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `class=col-xs-12` to the inner ng-repeat:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="(i, t) in h.data">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/92z54z04/957/